# while nested in for loop. How does the decrement operator work?

Tags: java

I couldn't figure out how the decrement operator (e--) 
works in code below, so i wrote the other class below it
to get the same result. I want to know how the decrement operator 
achieves that result in the Power class. - Newbie.

```
int result, e; 
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) { 
  result = 1; 
  e = i; 
  while(e > 0) { 
    result *= 2; 
    e--; 
  } 

  System.out.println("2 to the " + i +  
                     " power is " + result);        
}
```

Code written to achieve same result

```
int result = 1; 

for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) { 


  if (i > 0) {
  result*=2;

  }
  System.out.println("2 to the " + i +  
                     " power is " + result);

}
```

Comment: "Power class" = first code i have difficulty understanding

Comment: It would probably help you if you worked out a few small examples.

Comment: It would help if you asked a real question... what exactly is it you don't understand? `e` is decremented in the upper snippet, because the programmer probably did C before (it is faster in C to do it this way). It basically squares `result` `e` times

Comment: `When you say e-- you are using shorthand for e = e - 1.`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: Provided that you don't use the overall result of the expression, yes. But `x = e--;` and `x = (e = e - 1);` are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

So the first example is resetting result for each iteration of the main for loop, so it needs to recalculate from scratch each time, where as the second example is keeping the previous computed value.  The if in the second example is not needed is it.

Comment: the if is needed to get the first println statement for the answer to 2 to the 0 power. we can't double 2 zero times the way the code is written. that part is skipped. the rest are done with result *= 2;. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The decrement operator modifies the variable on which it's called. So `e--` is effectively `e = e - 1` (except the overall result of the expression is different, see below).

This code:

```
result = 1; 
e = i; 
while(e > 0) { 
  result *= 2; 
  e--; 
}
```

starts with `result = 1` and then loops for `i` iterations doubling the value in `result`. Equivalent code using `for` which you seem more comfortable with:

```
result = 1; 
for (e = 0; e < i; e++) {
  result *= 2; 
}
```

There are two forms of the decrement (and increment) operator: *Prefix* and *postfix*, depending on whether the operator is before (prefix) or after (postfix) its operand. Either could be used in the code you were asking about, because the only difference is the result of the expression.

**Prefix**: Suppose we have `x = 5`. The expression `--x` has the value `4`: First we decrement `x`, then we take its new value as the result of the expression.

**Postfix**: Suppose we had `x = 5` (again). The expression `x--` has the value `5`, with `x` ending up containing `4`: *First* we grab the current value of `x` as the result of the expression, then we decrement it (because the `--` is *after* `x`).

```
int x, r;

x = 5;
r = --x; // Prefix
System.out.println("r = " + r + ", x = " + x); // "r = 4, x = 4"

x = 5;
r = x--; // Postfix
System.out.println("r = " + r + ", x = " + x); // "r = 5, x = 4"
```

Comment: the two codes generate the same result, which is a series of the println statement, from i = 0 to i = 9. without the e-- bit in the first code, it doesn't get this result. i want to understand this. Also i understand the postfix-prefix thing. that understanding, questionable now perhaps, doesn't help me figure out the answer on my own, the answer as to why e-- squares result and keeps its value.   while e takes on the value of the iterating i, why is it decremented? I cringe at the thought that my question might be thought stupid. i badly want to understand this. thanks.

Comment: @user2869580: The first code is re-calculating the result each time. Your second code snippet keeps the previous result. In the first snippet, `e` doesn't have anything to do with calculating the result other than controlling the loop. The result is primarily calculated by the repeated `result *= 2` which doubles the value stored in `result` on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

i figure out that by placing a System.out.println(e) i could "see" the variable "e" behavior in order to make sense of the decrement.

```
class Power {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  int e;
  int result;

  for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
   result =1 ;
   e = i;

   while(e > 0) {
    System.out.println(e); // not part of the original program 
    result *= 2 ;            
    e--;
    System.out.println(e); // not part of the original program
```

}

```
//System.out.println("2 to the " + i +             
              //" power is " + result);
```

}

This is the output:

C:\Users\enrique\Desktop\Hello.java>java Power: 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3

e = 1(iteration 1), 2^1, e (1) decremented to 0, e = 2 (iteration 2), 2^2, e(2) decremented to 1, e = 1 re-enter The while but is ignored as 2^1 is already registered, e (1) decremented to 0, e = 3 (iteration 3), 2^3…